# How to watch TV with Me TV?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, totem, tv, dvb

Please help: Me TV doesn't start (why??) and installing `totem-plugins-dvb-daemon` doesn't show up in Totem itself - so I can't watch TV with Totem.

I installed `gnome-dvb-client` as well as `gnome-dvb-daemon`. I can scan for channels via `gnome-dvb-setup` and even record streams with `gnome-dvb-control` (and watch these streams later.)

I am looking for an easy to setup and easy to handle way for watching TV in Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric. Instead of Unity I chose GNOME-Shell.

I found a bug [here](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-dvb-daemon/+bug/846939):

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-dvb-daemon/ppa 
 sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now I can activate the DVB-Plugin in Totem and watch TV. But I have no idea why Me TV doesn't start. I was used to use this program in previous Ubuntu versions and would like to use it again.

Comment: I found a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-dvb-daemon/+bug/846939

    `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-dvb-daemon/ppa`
    `sudo apt-get update`
    `sudo apt-get upgrade`
Now I can activate the DVB-Plugin in Totem and watch TV.

But I have no idea why me-tv doesn't start - I was used to use this program in previous Ubuntu versions and would like to use it again...

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug and was solved by adding a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-dvb-daemon/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that, the user could activate the DVB-Plugin in Totem and watch TV.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried VLC? if you have the frequencies you just need to put them in VLC then it will play.

VLC Project WebSite: http://www.videolan.org

Comment: I want it easy to setup, I have no frequencies... But as written in the comment above I found a solution. (I couldn't post it as answer due to those "reputation points"...) Thanks anyway.